# React conditional rendering based on login logout and form submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, authentication

I am trying to initiate conditional rendering based on a form submit that goes to my node router but I am not getting the result. The buttons do not hide the content "ReminderModel" & "Reminder Table" and nothing happens when I submit the login form. I know this isnt the best way to do it but fi someone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it. I would prefer not to use another plugin for react and would prefer to do it on my own to avoid update conflicts, etc.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Button, Form, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';
import ReminderTable from './components/reminderList';
import ReminderModal from './components/modal';
const redColor = {
  color: '#e52d2d'
}


class App extends Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleLoginClick = this.handleLoginClick.bind(this);
    this.handleLogoutClick = this.handleLogoutClick.bind(this);
    this.LoginButton = this.LoginButton.bind(this);
    this.UponLoggedIn = this.UponLoggedIn.bind(this);
    this.NotLoggedIn = this.NotLoggedIn.bind(this);
      this.state = {
          user:[],
          isLoggedIn:false,
          username:'',
          password:''
        };
    }

    handleLoginClick() {
    this.setState({isLoggedIn: true});
  }

  handleLogoutClick() {
    this.setState({isLoggedIn: false});
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  }

  LoginButton = props => {
    return(
      <>
      <div id="status"></div>
        <Form
        className="loginForm"
          >
              <Form.Row>
              <Form.Group as={Col}>
              <Form.Label>Username</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control
                type="text"
                name="username"
                id="username"
                value={this.state.value}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                >
                </Form.Control>
              </Form.Group>
              <Form.Group as={Col}>
                <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control
                type="password"
                id="password"
                name="password"
                value={this.state.value}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
              </Form.Group>
              </Form.Row>
              <Button className="btn btn-sm btn-light" onClick={this.onSubmit}>
                <i style={redColor} className="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i> Login
              </Button>
        </Form>
      </>
    );
  }

 LogoutButton = props => {
    return(
      <>
      <Button className="btn btn-sm btn-light float-right" onClick={this.NotLoggedIn}>
        <i style={redColor} className="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Logout
      </Button>

      </>
    )
  }

NotLoggedIn = props => {
    return(
      <>
      <h4 className="text-muted"> Please Log in</h4>
      {this.LoginButton()}
      </>
    )

  }

UponLoggedIn = props => {
    return(
      <>
      <ReminderModal />
      <p className="text-muted text-center">If new reminder does not show up immediently please refresh page</p>
      <ReminderTable />
      </>
    )

  }

  ViewScreen = props => {
    const isLoggedIn = props.isLoggedIn;
    if(isLoggedIn){
      return this.UponLoggedIn();
    }else {
      return this.NotLoggedIn();
    }
  }



  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.get('api/user')
    .then(res => {
      const user = res.data[0].username;
      const password = res.data[0].password;
      const username = this.state.username;
      const passwordEntered = this.state.password;
      if(user === username && passwordEntered === password){
        if(username === '' && passwordEntered === ''){
          document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = '<p>Please Enter A Valid Username and Password</p>';
            this.NotLoggedIn();
        }else{
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = '<p>Please Enter A Valid Username and Password</p>';
              this.NotLoggedIn();
        }
        this.UponLoggedIn();
      }else {
        this.NotLoggedIn();
      }

    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });

  }

  render(){
    const isLoggedIn = this.state.isLoggedIn;
    let button;

    if (isLoggedIn) {
      button = this.LoginButton();
    } else {
      button = this.LogoutButton();
    }
    return (
      <div className="App container">
        <h4
        className="display-4 mt-4 mb-4 text-center"
        >
        <i style={redColor}
        className="fas fa-asterisk">
        </i> Expiration Reminder
        </h4>

        <Container isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}>{button}</Container>

      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this in a fairly simple way, keep in mind I have a back end with express that searches a predefined username and pass that is why I used axios to fetch that info and check against it in the onSubmit function.

FYI: if you're feeling lost with React or any language really just start by doing projects, that is how I am learning, I took a few Udemy courses but still didn't grasp it, I learned by doing and with each project(big or small) you pick up something new and/or gain a better understanding along the way. Just a little food for thought if you're like me and have a passion but don't know where or how to start.

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
      this.state = {
          user:[],
          isLoggedIn:false,
          username:'',
          password:''
        };
    }

     handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        });
      }

      handleLogoutClick = e => {
        this.setState({ isLoggedIn: false })
      }


  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.get('API_PATH')
    .then(res => {
      const user = res.data[0].username;
      const password = res.data[0].password;
      const username = this.state.username;
      const passwordEntered = this.state.password;
      if(user === username && passwordEntered === password){
          this.setState({ isLoggedIn:true })
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
          <h4
          className="display-4 mt-4 mb-4 text-center"
          >
          <i style={redColor}
          className="fas fa-asterisk">
          </i> Expiration Reminder
          </h4>


          <Container onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
              {this.state.isLoggedIn ? (
                <>
                <Button className="btn btn-sm btn-light mr-5 float-right" onClick={this.handleLogoutClick}>
                  <i style={redColor} className="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Logout
                </Button>
                <ReminderModal />
                <p className="text-muted text-center">If new reminder does not show up immediently please refresh page</p>
                <ReminderTable />
                </>
              ) : (
                <>
                <div id="status"></div>
                <Form className="loginForm ml-5">
                      <Form.Row>
                      <Form.Group as={Col}>
                      <Form.Label>Username</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        name="username"
                        id="username"
                        value={this.state.value}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        >
                        </Form.Control>
                      </Form.Group>
                      <Form.Group as={Col}>
                        <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control
                        type="password"
                        id="password"
                        name="password"
                        value={this.state.value}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        />
                      </Form.Group>
                      </Form.Row>
                      <Button className="btn btn-sm btn-light" onClick={this.onSubmit}>
                        <i style={redColor} className="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i> Login
                      </Button>
                    </Form>
                </>
              )}
          </Container>



      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `this.NotLoggedIn` in `onClick` handler, which is wrong, because `NotLoggedIn` returns React component. In the `onCLick` handler, you need to change state. So you should call `this.handleLoginClick` and `this.handleLogoutClick` instead.

Also there are couple of bugs. E.g. you are calling `button = this.LoginButton()`, but `LoginButton` functions expects `props`. You either have to pass the props to the function or you can access it in function as `this.props`.

Also the way you did it is kind of antipattern, because you are defining multiple components inside App component (LogoutButton, LoginButton etc.). You should split them into multiple classes.